# Wireless not working after maintenance on laptop

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, laptop

i was doing some maintenance on a laptop with overheating issues, but after i re-assembled it, it became apparent that the wlan chip doesnt show up in the 'network adapters' list, nor does it connect to anything. Checked device manager and it IS listed there though...

I figured i must've fried the chip somehow and tried to test it in another laptop, the chip was working fine though!

I checked the antennas, nothing out of the ordinary, the cables hadn't been messed with and there were no places where they could've become pinched or something, so i'm kind of confused..

some background info:
wlan chip: Atheros AR5B95 AR9285 802.11B/G/N Half Mini PCI-E Card
laptop: HP pavilion dv7-4030
OS: win7

after reassembly it bluescreened with something like a 'irql not less or equal' message but before i got to the laptop it seemed to have restarted automatically and booted normally after that, so i didnt think much of it

does anyone have any idea whats going on?

**EDIT: there wasnt anything wrong -_- Apparently i'm just an idiot. I checked if the laptop was fine on a guest account since i didnt have the password for an administrator account and it turned out that WLAN was disabled for guest accounts entirely.. Thanks for the tips though**

Comment: Not knowing exactly what you did in great detail or the methods you used to clean it inside try re-seating the wireless card then resetting bios to default values.

Answer (score 1):

Though I don't know specifically what is the issue, you might try uninstalling the adapter and drivers and then reinstalling them. Check Device Manager to see if there are multiple drivers or virtual adapters for the Atheros hardware.